# Evento tecla ENTER misma función que el click

Tags: java

Quiero que en mi aplicación la tecla **ENTER** sobre un button tenga el mismo efecto que un **click**.

Quiero que al presionar el `button_acceder` con el **ENTER** tenga el mismo efecto que el evento `actionPerformed()`.

**Código de click:**

```
private void button_accederActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        String usuario = textfield_usuario.getText();
        String password = textfield_password.getText();

        if(Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD("agenda") == null){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡MySQL failed!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            this.dispose();
        } else if(Conexiones.cargar_administradores(usuario, password).size()>0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Bienvenido "+usuario+"!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            Index i = new Index();
            i.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡No existe!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

Como véis, en este código: **si existe un usuario-contraseña, nos lleva a Index.java.**

¿Cómo completaría de la misma forma "private void button_accederKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)"

**Planteamiento:**

```
private void button_accederKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                           
    char c = (char) evt.getKeyCode();
    if(c == evt.VK_ENTER){
        //¿tengo que poner el mismo código entero de actionPerformed o puedo llamar
        //a la función actionPerformed aquí?
    }
}
```

Comment: Desde un evento se debe de poder llamar al otro. Podrias probar if(c == evt.VK_ENTER){ miButton.click();

Comment: @Jesús No funciona esa solución en mi caso.

Comment: es que has hecho unos voids raros. En vez de añadir una clase que bien pueda ser externa e independiente, interna o interna anónima que implementen los listeners. Es más sencillo de esa manera. Y desde el evento de teclado se puede perfectamente llamar al método doClick()

Comment: @Jesús No son "voids" raros. Son los voids que se generan al crear un evento de un componente en Java Swing. Cuando das boton derecho Event y buscas el evento se genera ese void. No es que sea raro.

Comment: Debe ser cosa del IDE. Seguramente sea NetBeans... el NetBeans incluye siempre códigos raros. El eclipse es más lógico, incluso con el addon visual WindowBuilder genera códigos más lógicos de entender. Te dejo una respuesta con un código manual, nada de generación de código automática.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este es un ejemplo de clase interna para los 2 eventos sobre el botón.

```
EventosTecladoRaton eventoTecladoYRaton = new EventosTecladoRaton();
Mi_Boton.addKeyListener(eventoTecladoYRaton);
Mi_Boton.addActionListener(eventoTecladoYRaton);

private class EventosTecladoRaton extends java.awt.event.KeyAdapter implements java.awt.event.ActionListener{

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    codigo de lo que hace el boton sea como sea que se accione
  }

  public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e){
    if (e.getExtendedKeyCode()==VK_ENTER) Mi_Boton.doClick();
  }
```